# G is a group if and only if for all $a,b∈G$, $ax=b$ has solution; true or false? Why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

[image: I think we only need $ax=b$ or $ya=b$ have solutions in $G$, i'll prove it.]

I think we only need $ax=b$ or $ya=b$ have solutions in $G$, I'll prove it.

Proof:

(I)

$G$ is a group $\implies$ $a^{-1}ax=a^{-1}b$ $\implies$ $x=a^{-1}b$ $\implies$ $ax=b$ has solutions in $G$

(II)

(A)
$ax=b$ has solutions in $G$ $\implies$ $ax=a$ has solutions in $G$ $\implies$ there exists an identity element $e∈G$ such that $ae=ea=a$

(B)
$ax=b$ has solutions in $G$ $\implies$ $ax=e$ has solutions in $G$ $\implies$ there exists an inverse element $a^{-1}∈G$ such that $ae=ea=a$

Hence, $ax=b$ has solutions in the semigroup $G$ (for all $a,b\in G$) if and only if $G$ is a group.

Correct?

Reference: Fraleigh p. 49 Question 4.39 in A First Course in Abstract Algebra

Comment: Much more is needed. We need to know, for example, that there is an $e$ such that for **all** $a$ we have $ae=a$. You have only proved that given $a$, there is an object $e_a$ such that $ae_a=a$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: what's the different,in my proof,a can be anything in G

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Also, doesn't it only show a one-sided identity? Not that it is two-sided? (Similar for the inverses?)

Comment: @Clayton one-sided identity=>two sided identity

Comment: @jujuju: That isn't true. I had to give a counterexample in my class :)

Comment: @Clayton: That too! I was mentioning only the first error in the OP.

Comment: @Clayton ea=a => aa^(-1)a=a =>ae=a

Comment: @jujuju: You showed that given $a$, there is an object $e_a$ (which may depend on $a$) such that $ae_a=a$. A right-identity $e$ must work for all $a$.

Comment: @André Nicolas you think e isn't unique in my proof?

Comment: You have not proved that the same $e$ works for all $a$. The uniqueness question has not been addressed.

Comment: if we know a^(-1)a=e ea=a .then(aa^(-1))(aa^(-1))=a(a^(-1)a)a^(-1)=(ae)a^(-1)=a(ea^(-1))=aa^(-1) =>aa^(-1)=e ,ea=a => aa^(-1)a=a =>ae=a.so left =>right

Comment: @André Nicolas you are right:) could you show me how to prove proposition 1.4 ,thx

Comment: If you use only the assumption that $ax=b$ always has a solution then you have easy non-group examples. Take any set $S$ with more than one element, and define the operation on $A$ to be the second projection, i.e., $pq=q$ for all $p,q\in S$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As has been pointed out in comments, there are gaps in the proof as it stands.

We give a start towards a correct proof. We will need the solvability of **both** types of equation, $ax=b$ and $ya=b$.

Let $a$ be some fixed element of our semigroup. By what you wrote, there is an object $e_a$ such that $ae_a=a$.

We show that $be_a=b$ for **any** $b$. To show this, observe that there is a $y$ such that $b=ya$. Multiplying on the right by $\color{darkcyan}{e_a}$, we get
$$\begin{align} b\color{darkcyan}{e_a} & = (ya)\color{darkcyan}{e_a} \\ &= y(a\color{darkcyan}{e_a})  \\ &= ya \\&= b \end{align}$$

This shows that our semigroup has a right identity.

In a similar way, one can show that the semigroup has a left identity.

It is quite easy to show that if $e_r$ is a right identity and $e_l$ is a left identity then $e_r=e_l$.

Showing the existence of the inverse of any $b$ is left to you.